I am want to add a simple gpu lidar sensor to my custom wheeled robot, but it's topic doesn't publish messages. I am using ros2 jazzy+gazebo harmonic
This is my URDF file part about laser(I was thinking that the problem is with measurments of lidar_head_link):
<gazebo reference="lidar_head_link">
    <sensor type="gpu_lidar" name="lidar_head_link">
          <gz_frame_id>lidar_head_link</gz_frame_id>
          <topic>scan</topic>
          <update_rate>10</update_rate>          
          <pose>0 0 2.0 0 0 0</pose>
          <lidar>
            <scan>
              <horizontal>
                <samples>640</samples>
                <resolution>1</resolution>
                <min_angle>-3.14</min_angle>
                <max_angle>3.14</max_angle>
              </horizontal>
              <vertical>
                <samples>16</samples>
                <resolution>1</resolution>
                <min_angle>-0.261799</min_angle>
                <max_angle>0.261799</max_angle>
              </vertical>
            </scan>
            <range>
              <min>0.08</min>
              <max>10.0</max>
              <resolution>0.01</resolution>
            </range>
          </lidar>
          <visualize>true</visualize>
          
    </sensor>
 </gazebo>

This is part about lidar_head_link(It spawns correctly in gz):
    <joint name="laser_joint" type="fixed">
     <parent link="base"/>
     <child link="lidar_head_link"/>
     <origin xyz="0.1 0 0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
   </joint>
   <link name="lidar_head_link">
      <visual>
         <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
         <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.04" radius="0.05"/>
         </geometry>
         <material name="laser_material">
            <color rgba="0.13 0.13 0.13 1.0"/>
         </material>
      </visual>
      <collision>
         <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
         <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.04" radius="0.05"/>
         </geometry>
      </collision>
   </link>

I also added line about remapping with specific namespace:
  <plugin filename="gz-sim-sensors-system" name="gz::sim::systems::Sensors">
    <render_engine>ogre2</render_engine>
      <ros>
        <namespace>/box_bot</namespace>
          <remapping>~/out:=scan</remapping>
      </ros>
    <output_type>sensor_msgs/LaserScan</output_type>

This is part about ros2_control(i have 2 controlled wheels, 1 uncontrolled and 3 joints to rotate them)
    <gazebo>
        <plugin filename="gz_ros2_control-system" name="gz_ros2_control::GazeboSimROS2ControlPlugin">
            <parameters>absolute_path_to_my_package/config/rotation_controller.yaml</parameters>
            <ros>
                <remapping>/controller_manager/robot_description:=/robot_description</remapping>
            </ros>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>

My launch file looks like this:
import os
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.substitutions import Command, FindExecutable
from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess, IncludeLaunchDescription, DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import PathJoinSubstitution, LaunchConfiguration
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.actions import RegisterEventHandler, SetEnvironmentVariable
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessExit
def generate_launch_description():
    pkgPath = FindPackageShare(package='three_legged_robot').find('three_legged_robot')
    world_path = os.path.join(pkgPath, 'worlds', 'mad_world.sdf')
    urdfModelPath = os.path.join(pkgPath, 'urdf/three_wheeled.urdf.xacro')
    
    with open(urdfModelPath, 'r') as infp:
        robot_desc = infp.read()
    gazebo_launch = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([PathJoinSubstitution([FindPackageShare('ros_gz_sim'), 'launch', 'gz_sim.launch.py'])]),
                launch_arguments=[("gz_args", [world_path])])

    robot_controllers = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [
            FindPackageShare('three_legged_robot'),
            'config',
            'rotation_controller.yaml',
        ]
    )
    
    control_node = Node(
    package="controller_manager",
    executable="ros2_control_node",
    parameters=[robot_controllers,
                '/robot_description'],
    output="both"
    )

    robot_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        parameters=[{'robot_description': robot_desc}],
        output='screen'
    )

    # Robot spawn node
    robot_spawn_node = Node(
        package='ros_gz_sim',
        executable='create',
        arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description',
                   '-entity', 'robot', '-r'],
        output='screen'
    )

    # RQT reconfigure node
    rqt_reconfigure_node = Node(
        package='rqt_gui',
        executable='rqt_gui',
        output='screen'
    )

    # Controller spawners
    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        arguments=['joint_state_broadcaster'],
    )

    rotation_controller_spawner = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        arguments=['rotation_controller',
                   '--controller-manager',
                   '/controller_manager'],
        output='screen'
    )

    wheel_controller_spawner = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        arguments=['wheel_controller',
                   '--controller-manager',
                   '/controller_manager'],
        output='screen'
    )
    bridge_params = os.path.join(pkgPath,'config','gz_bridge.yaml')
    bridge = Node(
        package="ros_gz_bridge",
        executable="parameter_bridge",
        arguments=[
            '--ros-args',
            '-p',
            f'config_file:={bridge_params}',]
    )
    start_rviz_cmd = Node(
    package='rviz2',
    executable='rviz2',
    name='rviz2',
    output='screen')
    joint_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher',
        executable='joint_state_publisher',
        output='screen'
    )
    
    return LaunchDescription([
        control_node,
        gazebo_launch,
        robot_spawn_node,
        # slam_launch,
        RegisterEventHandler(
            event_handler=OnProcessExit(
                target_action=robot_spawn_node,
                on_exit=[joint_state_broadcaster_spawner],
            )
        ),

        # Launch controller spawners after joint state broadcaster
        RegisterEventHandler(
            event_handler=OnProcessExit(
                target_action=joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
                on_exit=[rotation_controller_spawner, wheel_controller_spawner],
            )
        ),

        # Launch Gazebo-ROS bridge
        bridge,

        # Launch robot state publisher
        robot_state_publisher_node,

        # Launch RQT reconfigure node
        rqt_reconfigure_node,

        # Launch joint state publisher node
        joint_state_publisher_node,

        # Launch RViz
        start_rviz_cmd
    ])

This is my yaml files for controller(rotation_controller.yaml):
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 50 #Hz
    rotation_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController
    wheel_controller:
      type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController
    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
    
rotation_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - q1
      - q2 
      - q3
    command_interfaces:
      - position
    state_interfaces:
      - position
    open_loop_control: false
    allow_integration_in_goal_trajectories: true
    allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end: true

wheel_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    left_wheel_names: ["q10"]
    right_wheel_names: ["q11"]
    command_interfaces:
      - velocity
    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity
    wheel_separation: 0.33072
    wheels_per_side: 1
    wheel_radius: 0.025
    wheel_separation_multiplier: 1.0
    left_wheel_radius_multiplier: 1.0
    right_wheel_radius_multiplier: 1.0

And for a bridge(gz_bridge.yaml):
- topic_name: "/scan"
  ros_type_name: "sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan"
  gz_type_name: "gz.msgs.LaserScan"
  lazy: true
  direction: GZ_TO_ROS

- topic_name: "/scan/points"
  ros_type_name: "sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2"
  gz_type_name: "gz.msgs.PointCloudPacked"
  lazy: true
  direction: GZ_TO_ROS

This is my world file(mad_world.sdf):


<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.9">
  <world name="complex_maze_world">

    <physics name="default_physics" default="true" type="ode">
      <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
      <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
      <real_time_update_rate>1000</real_time_update_rate>
    </physics>
    <scene>
      <ambient>0.4 0.4 0.4 1</ambient>
      <background>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</background>
      <shadows>true</shadows>
    </scene>

    <light type="directional" name="sun">
      <cast_shadows>true</cast_shadows>
      <pose>0 0 10 0 0 0</pose>
      <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
      <specular>0.2 0.2 0.2 1</specular>
      <attenuation>
        <range>1000</range>
        <constant>0.9</constant>
        <linear>0.01</linear>
        <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
      </attenuation>
      <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
    </light>

    <model name="ground_plane">
      <static>true</static>
      <link name="link">
        <collision name="collision">
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0 0 1</normal>
              <size>100 100</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
        </collision>
        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0 0 1</normal>
              <size>100 100</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <ambient>0.2 0.8 0.8 0.2</ambient>
            <diffuse>0.2 0.8 0.8 0.2</diffuse>
            <specular>0.2 0.8 0.8 0.2</specular>
          </material>
        </visual>
      </link>
    </model>

    <!-- Outer Walls -->
    <model name="outer_wall_north">
      <static>true</static>
      <pose>0 10 1.5 0 0 0</pose>
      <link name="link">
        <collision name="collision"><geometry><box><size>26 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></collision>
        <visual name="visual"><geometry><box><size>26 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></visual>
      </link>
    </model>
    <model name="outer_wall_south">
      <static>true</static>
      <pose>0 -10 1.5 0 0 0</pose>
      <link name="link">
        <collision name="collision"><geometry><box><size>26 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></collision>
        <visual name="visual"><geometry><box><size>26 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></visual>
      </link>
    </model>
    <model name="outer_wall_east">
      <static>true</static>
      <pose>13 0 1.5 0 0 1.57</pose>
      <link name="link">
        <collision name="collision"><geometry><box><size>20 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></collision>
        <visual name="visual"><geometry><box><size>20 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></visual>
      </link>
    </model>
    <model name="outer_wall_west">
      <static>true</static>
      <pose>-13 0 1.5 0 0 1.57</pose>
      <link name="link">
        <collision name="collision"><geometry><box><size>20 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></collision>
        <visual name="visual"><geometry><box><size>20 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></visual>
      </link>
    </model>


    <!-- Inner Walls - More complex layout -->
    <model name="inner_wall_1"><static>true</static><pose>-9 3 1.5 0 0 0</pose><link name="link"><collision name="collision"><geometry><box><size>8 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></collision><visual name="visual"><geometry><box><size>8 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></visual></link></model>
    <model name="inner_wall_2"><static>true</static><pose>5 -4 1.5 0 0 1.57</pose><link name="link"><collision name="collision"><geometry><box><size>9 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></collision><visual name="visual"><geometry><box><size>9 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></visual></link></model>
    <model name="inner_wall_3"><static>true</static><pose>-5 0 1.5 0 0 1.57</pose><link name="link"><collision name="collision"><geometry><box><size>7 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></collision><visual name="visual"><geometry><box><size>18 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></visual></link></model>
    <model name="inner_wall_4"><static>true</static><pose>9 -5 1.5 0 0 0</pose><link name="link"><collision name="collision"><geometry><box><size>8 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></collision><visual name="visual"><geometry><box><size>8 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></visual></link></model>
    <model name="inner_wall_5"><static>true</static><pose>5 6 1.5 0 0 1.57</pose><link name="link"><collision name="collision"><geometry><box><size>5 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></collision><visual name="visual"><geometry><box><size>5 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></visual></link></model>
    <model name="inner_wall_6"><static>true</static><pose>9 5 1.5 0 0 0</pose><link name="link"><collision name="collision"><geometry><box><size>8 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></collision><visual name="visual"><geometry><box><size>8 0.2 3</size></box></geometry></visual></link></model>

    

  </world>
</sdf>

So robot spawns correctly and I can publish messages about its speed. The problem only with sensor. gz topic -e -t /scan gives no messages, rviz2 gives empty point cloud. UPD: /scan isn't in gz topic -l(I looked on yesterday's state)
